# Largest number of bits in error that is guaranteed to be detected in CRC

Tags: networking, computer-science, crc

I have a few questions about CRC:

1. How can I tell, for a given CRC polynom and a n-bits data, what is the largest number of bits in error that is guaranteed to be detected?
2. Is it true that ALWAYS - the bigger the polynom degree, the more errors that can be detected from that CRC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that "How many errors can it detect" is the largest number of bits in error that is always guaranteed to be detected.

1. You would need to search for the minimum weight codeword of length *n* for that polynomial, also referred to as its Hamming distance. The number of bit errors that that CRC is guaranteed to detect is one less than that minimum weight. There is no alternative to what essentially amounts to a brute-force search. See Table 1 in [this paper by Koopman](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/networks/dsn02/dsn02_koopman.pdf) for some results. As an example, for messages 2974 or fewer bits in length, the standard CRC-32 has a Hamming distance of no less than 5, so any set of 4 bit errors would be detected.
2. Not necessarily. Polynomials can vary widely in quality. Given the performance of a polynomial on a particular message length, you can always find a longer polynomial that has worse performance. However a well-chosen longer polynomial should in general perform better than a well-chosen shorter polynomial. However even there, for long message lengths you may find that both have a Hamming distance of two.

Comment: First- Thanks. I updated my question. now.. 1. I know that Hamming code is depend on the Hammaing distance. Why CRC too? even if there are 2 vaild words that have 1 bit distance, they will have diffrent CRC so that if 1 error will occur, when can detect it even if the distance is 1. Am I right?

Comment: 2. If let's say, the data length is n and the degree of the polinomial is greater then n, let's say x, so if I'll choose y>x - and they both will be well-chosen, so it'll guaranteed to have improvement?

Comment: An _n_ -bit codeword for the polynomial has CRC zero. Since CRC's are linear, you can exclusive-or that codeword with any _n_ -bit message. Then the CRC of the message before and after the exclusive-or is the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not a question of 'how many'. It's a question of what *proportion* and what *kind*. 'How many' depends on those things and on the length of the input.
2. Yes.

Comment: 1. CRC is designed to detect comon errors in a given situation.

from wikipedia : 

> CRCs are specifically designed to protect against common types of errors on communication channels, where they can provide quick and reasonable assurance of the integrity of messages delivered. However, they are not suitable for protecting against intentional alteration of data.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: @Pierrot Your comment should be addressed to the OP. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with this answer. NB WIkipedia is not a reliable resource, as it says itself.